# fiddler script send http request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fiddler

i need to send http request in onBeforeResponse method.
i am trying to add this method in CustomRules.js

```js
static function httpGet(theUrl){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
  xmlHttp.send( null );
  return xmlHttp.responseText;
 }
```

but i have an error `"XMLHttpRequest" is not defined`
There are any way how to send http request from fiddler script rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddler doesn't have a browser object model, so `XMLHttpRequest` isn't defined. Fortunately, it offers many different ways to send HTTP requests; e.g.:

```
var oSD = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary();
var newSession = FiddlerApplication.oProxy.SendRequestAndWait(oSession.oRequest.headers, oSession.requestBodyBytes, oSD, null);
if (200 == newSession.responseCode)
{
 //....
}
```